# Prove that if an existential formula A is satisfiable in a countable structure, then it's valid

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**Question**
Prove that if an existential formula A is satisfiable in EVERY countable structure, then it's valid.

**Proof:**
My proof is that $B=\lnot A$ is universal so if B is not satisfiable in any countable structure $\iff$ B is not satisfiable in any structure (using Lewenheim Skolem upward theorem) $\iff$ A is valid.

This proof is wrong, as I've saw a hint about using Herbrand's theorem. I want to understand what is wrong with my proof, and how is this proven using Hebrand's theorem.

Comment: The theorem can't be correct as stated; the formula $(\exists x)[f(x) = c]$ in the language $\{ f, c\}$ is satisfiable in a countable structure, and so is its negation. so the formula is not valid. There must be additional assumptions in the result you are trying to prove?

Comment: Consider $\exists x P(x)$. ... // If $A$ is existential and satisfiable in a countable structure, then it doesn't follow that $\neg A$ is *not* satisfiable in any countable structure. // "Lowenheim", with an 'o'. More precisely, "Löwenheim" with an 'ö'

Comment: question was fixed now.

Comment: Is $A$ allowed to have free variables: or did you mean to say "existential sentence" rather than "existential formula"? Are you working in a countable language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Herbrand's theorem seems to be overkill. I would say:

Assume that $A$ is true in every finite or countable structure, and that $A$ is not logically valid. We seek a contradiction.

Since $A$ is not logically valid. Then $A$ is false in some structure $M$. Since $A$ is assumed true in every finite structure, $M$ must be infinite. By the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, $M$ is elementarily equivalent to a countable structure, but this is a contradiction because $A$ was assumed to be true in every countable structure.

It is necessary for the truth of the claim that "countable" means "finite or countable". If we require $A$ to be true only in countably infinite structures, then $A\equiv \exists x\exists y(x\ne y)$ is a counterexample -- it is true in every countably infinite structure, but is not logically valid, because it is false in a structure with one element.

Comment: But what if $A$ has free variables?

Comment: @Rob: Hmm... I imagined they could either be replaced by constant symbols or closed over, but you may be onto something there. I see now that the OP speaks about $A$ being _satisfiable_ in every structure, which implicitly quantifies the variables _existentially_, whereas the conclusion about logical validity implicitly quantifies them _universally_...

Comment: I meant a closed universal formula (I'm still not that familiar with the English terminology.. sorry)

Comment: "Closed formula"  or "sentence" are usual terms for a formula with no free variables. A closed universal (respectively existential) formula is one of the form $\forall x_1 \dots \forall x_n\phi$ (respectively $\exists x_1 \dots \exists x_n\phi$where the $x_i$ contain all the free variables of $\phi$.  I think you mean that $A$ is a closed *existential* formula here. Is that right?

Comment: Assuming the language is countable and $A$ is a sentence and that "countable" includes "finite" then you don't need Löwenheim-Skolem either: given a structure $M$, choose an $x \in M$ and let $N$ be the substructure of $M$ generated by $x$, then $A$ holds in $N$ and hence, because $A$ is purely existential, it also holds in $M$.